# How to use SetDataSource Method of the Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Has anyone been able to use setdatasource method of the kendo UI grid? I believe this is used to assign datasource that can be assigned to the grid at the later stage and also for grid refresh purposes. However i couldn't find any proper documentation that explains how to use this method and make refreshable grid.

I am  trying to update my datasource via remote ajax call. I also assumed that it should autorefresh when the source is updated by setting the autosync property to true. Everytime i click the calendar control i pass in a date value to the GetRemoteData function so that the data is updated via the ajax request.

This doesn't work at the moment. Any clue as to what is the solution for this?

**My View**

```
    $('#calendarContainer').kendoCalendar({
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
        culture: "en-GB",
        change: onDateChange
    });


 function onDateChange() {
        var selectedDate = kendo.toString(this.value(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');

        GetRemoteData(selectedDate);
        /*
         $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(bob);
         $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        */
    }



   $('#grid').kendoGrid({

            dataSource:GetRemoteData(date),

            scrollable: {
                virtual: true
            },
            navigatable: true,
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            selectable: "row",
            pageable: true,

            pageable: {
                input: true,
                numeric: false
            },

            resizable: true,
            reorderable: true,
            filterable: {
                extra: false
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "DealNumber",
                    width: 150,
                    title: "DealNumber",
                    filterable: {
                        operators: {
                            string: {
                                startswith: "Starts With",
                                contains: "Contains"
                            }
                        }

                    },

                },
               {
                   field: "DealIssuer",
                   width: 150,
                   title: "Issuer",
                   filterable: {
                       operators: {
                           string: {
                               startswith: "Starts With",
                               contains: "Contains"
                           }
                       }
                   }

               },
                  {
                      field: "Ticker",
                      width: 150,
                      title: "Ticker",
                      filterable: {
                          operators: {
                              string: {
                                  startswith: "Starts With",
                                  contains: "Contains"
                              }
                          }
                      }

                  },
                     {
                         field: "DealType",
                         width: 150,
                         title: "Type",
                         filterable: {
                             operators: {
                                 string: {
                                     startswith: "Starts With",
                                     contains: "Contains"
                                 }
                             }
                         }

                     },
                        {
                            field: "DealValue",
                            width: 150,
                            title: "Value",
                            filterable: {
                                operators: {
                                    string: {
                                        startswith: "Starts With",
                                        contains: "Contains"
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        },
                           {
                               field: "DealStatus",
                               width: 150,
                               title: "Status",
                               filterable: {
                                   operators: {
                                       string: {
                                           startswith: "Starts With",
                                           contains: "Contains"
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                           },
                 {
                     field: "DealPricingCompletionDate",
                     width: 230,
                     title: "DealPricingCompletionDate",
                     format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
                     //  template: '#= kendo.toString(StartDate, "dd/MM/yyyy") #',
                     filterable: {
                         ui: "datetimepicker",
                         operators: {
                             date: {
                                 gt: "After",
                                 lt: "Before",
                                 eq: "Equals"
                             },
                             messages: {
                                 filter: "Apply",
                                 clear: "Clear"
                             }
                         }

                     }
                 },

                 {
                     command: { text: "View Details", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: "140px"
                 },

            ],
            editable: "popup",
            height: 600
        }).data("kendoGrid");






function GetRemoteData(date) {

        var chosenDate;


        if (typeof date == "undefined") {
            chosenDate = "12-12-2013";
        }
        else {
            chosenDate = date;
        }

       var  source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            autoSync: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/GetDealData",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: false,
                },

                parameterMap: function (data, type) {

                    var data = {
                        startDate: chosenDate
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        DealNumber: { type: "string" },
                        DealIssuer: { type: "string" },
                        Ticker: { type: "string" },
                        DealType: { type: "string" },
                        DealValue: { type: "number" },
                        DealStatus: { type: "string" },
                        DealPricingCompletionDate: { type: "date" }

                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 16
        });

        source.fetch(function () {
            var data = this.data();
        });
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: Kendo's documentation is amazing so long as you are making a website that lets the user select apples and bananas and does absolutely nothing of any real value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What have you tried so far? This is pretty basic.

Example:

```
var ddl = $('#testDropDown').data("kendoDropDownList");
var otherDropDownList= $('#otherDropDown').data("kendoDropDownList");

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource();
ds.data(otherDropDownList.dataSource.data()); // set new DataSource to otherDropDown's data source then filter it
ds.filter(
     {
         field: "Id",
         operator: "eq",
         value: parseInt(id)
     }
)

ddl.setDataSource(ds);
```

Obviously this is all going to be different for whichever scenario you have.

**Update for Grid**

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource();
var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");

grid.setDataSource(ds); // sets to a blank dataSource
```

Or, use this dataSource with another grid?

```
var gridDataSource = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
var secondGrid = $('#secondGrid').data("kendoGrid");

secondGrid.setDataSource(gridDataSource);
```

Comment: HI thedixon. Thank you for the code but i am trying to do the same with the Grid. I have tried all sorts of option but none worked until i came across this method called setDataSource. Would you be able to show the example like this for Grid. I can post my code if you want to see where it can be fit in.

Comment: Yep, if you could post your current code and what you're trying to do, that'd be great.

Comment: Updated my answer, still not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll see if i can refresh my datagrid contents dynamically with your suggestion.

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark the answer as accepted if it works and is able to help others :)

Comment: Hi thedixon the code var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid"); are you sure thats how we do it? cause my grid declaration is different to what you have showed me.

Comment: Further explanation has been added to the question

Comment: Hi thedixon. i modified by onDateChange Function with your code.    function onDateChange() {
           var selectedDate = kendo.toString(this.value(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');            
            GetRemoteData(selectedDate);
            var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
            grid.setDataSource(source);                      
          
        }. This worked like magic.                                                 You are a Kendo UI Champion/Superman. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Haha, thank you @Sike12 and I'm glad you got your solution all working, have fun with Kendo! :)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to set the setDataSource other way is creating a dataSource from the object returned by your ajax request as is explain in the following [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684678/how-to-set-list-as-kendo-grid-datasource-in-javascript) by [Brett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2701144/brett)

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: "your object returned by ajax"
});

$('#GridKatildigiKurslar').data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Off Course the grid should be configured to show the returned object.

Comment: Thank you @freedeveloper

Comment: according to this bug "https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/5966"
Seting datasource like above will set page size to NaN so to avoid it do this
//Code
   let dataSource = {
          data:[
          { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" }
        ]};

       $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(dataSource);