# angularjs directive kendoGrid repeating border

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

I have a directive for kendoGrid and that directive also has watch for an scope variable called

> objectSource

so that I can change the data upon some user interaction.

However, after the initial render, everytime the data gets updated, kendoGrid border is being duplicated. Here is the snap-shot of what it looks like: The kendoGrid wrapper has been applied numerous time.

[image: KendoGrid repeating border]

Here is what the directive looks like:

```
angular.module('foo.directives')
.directive('fooKendoUiGrid', ['kendoUIArgument', '$rootScope', function (kendoUIArgument, $rootScope) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            objectSource: '=',
            editcolumnWidth: '@',
            deletecolumnWidth: '@',
            columnList: '=',
            height: "@",
            pageSize: "@",
            buttonCount: "@",
            customFilter: '=',
            defaultColumn: '@'
        },

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.Headersloaded = false;
            scope.dataloaded = false;
            scope.increment = 0;
            if (!scope.id) {
                elem.id = "grid";
            } else {
                elem.id = scope.id;
            }

            scope.$watch('objectSource', function (newVal) {
                if (newVal && newVal.length > 0) {
                    elem[0].innerHTML = '';
                    elem[0].nextSibling.outerHTML = '';

                    if (scope.pageSize && scope.pageSize > 0) {
                        if (scope.columnList) {

                            } else {
                            elem.kendoGrid({
                                dataSource: { data: newVal, pageSize: parseInt(scope.pageSize), },
                                pageable: {
                                    buttonCount: parseInt(scope.buttonCount),
                                    pageSizes: true,
                                    refresh: true
                                },
                                columns: scope.columnList,
                                filterable: false,
                                columnMenu: false,
                                sortable: true,

                                height: scope.height
                            });

                        }
```

I tried to destroy the elem and empty it's content whenever data changes, but didn't help.

If I just change the datasource, I was able to resolve the issue, but not only data I have to change the columns too and Kendo doesn't seem to allow to change the columns dynamically.

Any ideas, suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any elegant solution.

I ended up doing something like this:

```
scope.$watch('objectSource', function (newVal, oldVal) {
if ($(elem.parent()).hasClass('k-grid')) {
   $(elem.parent()).replaceWith($(elem));
}
```

Every time the directive is rendered, kendoGrid added a border and when the directive got repainted, the border duplicated. So above jQuery code basically cleans up any div with border with the new directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the grid content by using kendo “SetDataSource()”

> var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource();
> var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid"); // or $element in the directive
>
> grid.setDataSource(ds); // sets to a blank dataSource

Reference answer:  [How to use SetDataSource Method of the Kendo UI Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014159/how-to-use-setdatasource-method-of-the-kendo-ui-grid)